# Quotient of two monotone function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ be two positive and monotone increasing sequences of real functions.

Is $\frac{f_n}{f_n+g_n}$ monotone? Does it converge?

**My thoughts**

$\frac{f_n}{f_n+g_n}=1-\frac{g_n}{f_n+g_n}=1+\frac{(-1)g_n}{f_n+g_n}$. As the numerator $(-1)g_n$ is monotone decreasing and the denominator monotone increasing, the quotient should be monotone decreasing.

If there is $N$ such that $\forall n>N$, the quotient is in some bounded subset (it is eventually bounded), then it converges.

Did I go in the right direction?

Comment: When the numerator is negative, dividing by a monotone increasing positive sequence _increases_ the result. So your reasoning doesn't hold

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence of functions to be increasing?  Do you mean e.g. pointwise increasing?  And what type of convergence are you looking for (e.g. pointwise convergence, uniform convergence, convergence in $L^p$ for some $p$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\frac {f_n} {f_n+g_n}=\frac1  {1+\frac {g_n} {f_n}}$. So this is montone iff  $\frac {g_n} {f_n}$ is monotone. It is easy to construct examples where the ratio of two positive increasing functions is not monotone. (Look at constant functions).  Also, the limit may not exist. I hope you can work out some exmaples.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is easier to think about in this form:
$$
\frac{f_n}{f_n + g_n} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{g_n}{f_n}}
$$

Now the question is, what behavior can $\frac{g_n}{f_n}$ have? Of course, as you might imagine, it can do just about anything. If $g_n$ is faster in growth than $f_n$, it tends to $\infty$. If $f_n$ grows faster than $g_n$, it tends to $0$. Or you could make it tend to any positive value you like. Or you can make it oscillate:$$
f_n = 1, 2, 5, 6, 13, 14, \ldots
$$
$$
g_n = 1, 4, 5, 12, 13, 28, \ldots
$$
$$
\frac{g_n}{f_n} = 1, 2, 1, 2, \dots
$$

So no, generally, the quotient is not monotone and does not converge.